# If two random variables are equal in the distribution, then the $\sigma$-algebra generated by them coincide

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $X$ in $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}_1,P_1)$ and $Y$ in $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}_2,P_2)$ two real random variables such that $X=Y$ in distribution.

The question is:

The $\sigma$-algebras $\sigma_{X}:=\{ A\in \mathfrak{F}_1: A=X^{-1}(B),\mbox{ for all }  B\in\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})  \}$ and $\sigma_{Y}$ generated by $X$ and $Y$ are the same?

I think the answer is not, in the case $P_{1} \neq P_2$, but I need to show a counterexample of this.

And in the case $P_1=P_2$ I don't know. Maybe is truth.

Comment: Not sure why you changed the base $\sigma$-algebra, but no, this is definitely not the case even when the underlying probability space is fixed. If it were then the interpretation of $\sigma$-algebras as "information" in probability theory would be dead on arrival.

Comment: Of course, having the same distribution does not imply that one generates the same sigma-algebra. For a simple counterexample, consider $\mathfrak F_1=\mathfrak F_2$, $P_1=P_2$, and $X$ and $Y$ i.i.d. Bernoulli, then the only events $A$ in $\sigma_X\cap\sigma_Y$ are such that $P(A)$ is $0$ or $1$. For example, $\{X=1\}\in\sigma_X\setminus\sigma_Y$.